# Counting objects in a specific area of the frame

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection

I want to track objects and count them in the lower half of the frame but I want the width to be a little bit smaller than the actual one like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELen1.jpg)

This is the code I wrote but it count objects with the center coordinates under h-350

def count_obj(box,w,h,id):
global count,data

```
center_coordinates = (int(box[0]+(box[2]-box[0])/2) , int(box[1]+(box[3]-box[1])/2))
if int(box[1]+(box[3]-box[1])/2) <(h-350):

    if  id not in data:
        
        count += 1
        data.append(id)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
center_coordinates = (int(box[0]+(box[2]-box[0])/2) , int(box[1]+(box[3]-box[1])/2))
if int(box[1]+(box[3]-box[1])/2) <(h-350):
    if int(box[0]+(box[2]-box[0])/2) <(w-10):
        if  id not in data:
        
            count += 1
            data.append(id)
```

Something like this work ? I assumed a lot of things, if you can provide a working detailed example it's better.